# Error 500 invocar web services haciendo una llamada AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, webservice

Tengo un problema, no logro invocar un *Web Service* hecho en C# desde una llamada AJAX usando Javascript y jQuery.

Esta es la llamada:

```
function authenticate() {
    var name = $("#username").val();
    var pwd = $("#password").val();
    var baseurl = getbaseurl();
    $.ajax({
        //url: getlocalurl() + "WebServices/Seguridad.asmx/Autenticar",
        url: "http://localhost:59952/WebServices/Seguridad.asmx",
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            usuario: name,
            clave: pwd
        },
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        crossdomain: true,
        success: OnSuccess,
        //traditional: true,
        error: function (result) {
            $("#errorLabel").show();
            $("#password").val("");
        }
    });
}
```

Este es el método del *Web Service*:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
[ScriptService]
public class Seguridad : IntranetWebService.IntranetWebService
{
    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public void Autenticar(string usuario, string clave)
    {
        try
        {
            Usuario entidadUsuario = ControladorSeguridad.ValidarUsuario(usuario, clave);
            // Si se autentica, se graba en el registro del usuario, el session Id correspondiente para validar los accesos de los servicios web
            if (entidadUsuario.Id > -1)
            {
                sessionId = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                ControladorSeguridad.GrabarSessionId(entidadUsuario.Id, sessionId);
                FachadaSesion.UsuarioAutenticado = entidadUsuario;

                InicializarDti(0, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(entidadUsuario), sessionId);
            }
            else
                InicializarDti(LoginErroneo, "", ERROR);
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            InicializarDti(Excepcion, ex.Message, EXCEPTION);
        }
        finally
        {
            RetornarDatos();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hola Matti, bienvenid@ a [es.so], ¿has intentado consumir el webservice desde algún navegador, o alguna herramienta como Postman, Fiddler, SoapUI?

Comment: Hola Flxtr Gracias por tu respuesta, voy a intentar con Postman, te mantengo al tanto!

Comment: Revisé el código y veo que consumes el servicio por método POST, pero en la definición tienes que es GET `UseHttpGet = true`, debes homologar el método a consumir y por ser validación de contraseñas sugiero que sea por POST, otra cosa, veo que consumes el servicio en `localhost`, entonces para que funcione debe estar activado en el IIS local o por lo menos en ejecución.

Comment: si tengo corriendo el IIS local,   y sobre el `ÙseHttpGet` asi lo tengo funcionando en otro sitio, que yo no programe obviamente, pero funciona sin problemas.

Comment: Enviando GET en la llamada ajax funciona, y si necesito hacer un post? que utilzo en el webServices?

Comment: Para configurar el método POST debes ponerlo en el web.config: `<location path="YourWebservice.asmx">
  <system.web>
    <webServices>
      <protocols>
        <add name="HttpPost"/>
      </protocols>
    </webServices>
  </system.web>
</location>`

Comment: Exelente! Muchisimas Gracias!

Comment: Hola buenas tardes, por curiosidad, ¿Lograste hacer funcionar el código?

Comment: Otra que ha solucionado ese problema es agregando [WebInvoke(Method="POST",ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json)] y como dice Phi hay que configurar el metodo POST en el web.config 
https://pastebin.com/CbhjsXZj

Comment: Se debé al como estas enviando tus parametros debes convertirlos con el comando JSON.stringify()

Answer (score 0):

El JSON que le envías por POST tendría que estar serializado o sino directamente se lo puedes pasar así:

```
data: "{'usuario': '" + usuario + "'," +
            "'password': '" + password + "'}"
```